# Responding to paternity questions?

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

A new question today was [Distinguishing 3rd cousin from half sibling?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/13488/distinguishing-3rd-cousin-from-half-sibling) which I think amounts to a question of paternity for the asker who wants to know whether a person he knows is his half sister.

I think we have already had a few similar questions and are likely to get more.

Would using the question below as a duplicate for such questions make sense?

[How can I determine the likely relationship based upon autosomal DNA shared cM?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/13459)

Answer (score 3):

I think that's a very good idea. We can never do more than point to a resource like that; there's very little to be gained for other readers in somebody else's particular family circumstances.

Answer (score 3):

When the question can be answered simply by looking up values in a chart, it may be a duplicate. We need to be cognizant that the the poster's background knowledge will vary widely, and that the technology itself is changing. That is, the referenced answer may not be enough.

Comment: Perhaps we can, at least initially, try to provide an answer before closing as a duplicate but have that answer explain how to use the duplicate.  I've now done that for that question.

Comment: @PolyGeo, how will that avoid duplicates -- once we've got that resource and an explanation of how to use it, what other value can we add. Perhaps editing the answer to the proposed duplicate to add more explanation would be the way forward.

Comment: @ColeValleyGirl I think that would work too, and maybe better. My thinking was that by using half a dozen signposts to the duplicate we could start to cater for the different ways of asking while letting the duplicate remain concise.